# #ember-power-select Trigger focus from an action

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I've been stuck on this issue for about a week now, and I am not exactly sure how to solve it.

What I am trying to do is set the focus of ember-power-select from triggering an

I am currently able to set focus to the power select via tabbing or clicking, however I can't seem to gain its focus from another action.

(Like the hacky way I can think of is to call handleFocus directly and pass a select object)

```
In Component.hbs:
{{#power-select 
  class='ls-search-box' 
  options=searchList 
  selected=selected 
  onfocus=(action "handleFocus") as |item| 
}}

In Component.js:
actions: { 
  handleFocus(select, e){ 
    select.actions.open()
  },
  focusSearch(){ 
    //console.log('focus Search'); 
    var input = Ember.$(".ls-search-box"); 
    if(input) {
      input.focus();
    } 
  }
}
```

Any know what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `focusSearch` like :

```
focusSearch(){ 
    //console.log('focus Search'); 
    var input = Ember.$(".ls-search-box >  .ember-power-select-trigger"); 
    if(input) {
      input.focus();
    } 
  }
```

You used a wrong css selector

Comment: Oh nice catch ty for pointing it out my mistake, but the issue still persist even with that change

I shall update the code

Comment: @yfjd01 I update my answer. The correct selector is there